# Node.js: File Upload API and JSON return

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, watson

I'm totally new to node.js, so I'm trying to find a way to create an image-file upload API, which returns a json after the process is finished. 
I'm using the Watson Developer Cloud (Visual Recognition), which returns a JSON after finishing the processing task.

I hope you have tips & ideas on how to get this project done. I thought about using the express library?

**This is my code, which processes a local image right now and logs the JSON result to the console. I want to be able to upload an image via api and return the JSON, after the process is done.**

Thanks a lot!

Code to process Image:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud') 
var fs = require('fs')  

//initialisng the service
var visual_recognition = watson.visual_recognition({ 
    api_key : '<Enter API Key here>',  
    version: 'v3',
    version_date: '2016-05-20' 
});   


var params = { 
    images_file: fs.createReadStream('./resources/image.jpg')
};  

visual_recognition.classify(params, function(err, res){ 
    if(err) 
        console.log(err); 
    else 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)); 
});
```

First Try for the upload Server (Thanks to @Eduard for the tip):

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) 


var app = express()

app.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    if(err){
        console.log("Error uploading file"); 
    }   
    console.log(req.file);  
    console.log(req.body); 

    res.status(204).end();
    console.log("Upload success"); 
}) 

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Upload Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Unfortunately this returns a 'ReferenceError: err is not defined[..]', while uploading an image with this simple Python Script:

```
import requests
url='http://localhost:3000/upload'
imageURL = 'ImageURL'

with open(imageURL, 'rb') as image:
    filename = image.name
    files = {'avatar': (image)}
    r = requests.request(method="POST", url=url, files=files)
    print(r.text);
    print(r.status_code)
```

---

Sidenote: 
Why do I want to use a Node.js Server? 
Unfortunately the Watson-Developer-Cloud Python SDK is not supported on my hardware (a robot) and using the API endpoint with a direct upload from python causes trouble due to the old python Version on the hardware (SNI Problems)

Answer (score 2):

At first, you will need **ExpressJS** to easily catch the POST, and secondly, you should be using **Multer**, as it is the easiest to work with when it comes to file uploading in my opinion.

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

*Example taken from Multer repo*

You have more info about checking the file itself here: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I added my first try to the question, unfortunately this does not work? (See error). Moreover: Do you have an idea on how to connect the two codes -> After uploading the image successfully, process the image?

Comment: @JSt Hello! You are trying to access an undefined variable called `err`. You need to call your middleware first. Please check my gist here: https://gist.github.com/EduardJS/21f6903b96c7659e64d118adfc5450fc